# Unreal Engine 4.10 is not creating c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, unreal-engine4

Hello I wanted to create a project in UE4.10 with basic c++ code. But when it comes to create it, UE gives me an error:

> The project could not be compiled. Would you like to open it in Visual Studio? Running E:/Program Files (x86)/Epic Games/4.10/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe MyProject Development Win64 -project="C:/Users/allst/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject/MyProject.uproject" -rocket -editorrecompile -progress -noubtmakefiles -2015 @progress push 5% Parsing headers for MyProjectEditor Running UnrealHeaderTool "C:/Users/allst/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject/MyProject.uproject" "C:\Users\allst\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject\Intermediate\Build\Win64\MyProjectEditor\Development\UnrealHeaderTool.manifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -rocket -installed Reflection code generated for MyProjectEditor in 17,8672852 seconds @progress pop Performing 7 actions (2 in parallel) [2/7] Resource PCLaunch.rc E:\Program Files (x86)\Epic Games\4.10\Engine\Source\Runtime\Launch\Resources\Windows\PCLaunch.rc(10) : fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'windows.h'. [3/7] Resource ModuleVersionResource.rc.inl E:\Program Files (x86)\Epic Games\4.10\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Resources\Windows\ModuleVersionResource.rc.inl(3) : fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'windows.h'. PCH.MyProject.h.cpp E:\Program Files (x86)\Epic Games\4.10\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\HAL\PlatformIncludes.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'new': No such file or directory -------- End Detailed Actions Stats ----------------------------------------------------------- ERROR: UBT ERROR: Failed to produce item: C:\Users\allst\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor-MyProject.dll Total build time: 90,64 seconds

I had VS 2013 pro, but I was asked to install VS 2015 community, what I have done, but problem is still persisting. Have you any ideas what should be done now? I will be gratefull for any advice. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify that "Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015" was selected when installing Visual Studio 2015. It will not automatically install, you need to do a custom install for that.

Answer (score 0):

It appear to be a known problem while running Unreal Engine prior to 4.12.5 with Visual Studio Community 2015 with Update 3.

Assuming that you already have *Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015* installed.
You can check if you are running VS2015 with Update 3 by going to:

`Visual Studio 2015` > `Help` > `About Microsoft Visual Studio`

## Solution 1: Update Unreal Engine > 4.12.5

Updating your Unreal Engine to version above 4.12.5

Go to
`Epic Game launcher` > `Unreal Engine` > `Library` > `Engine Version` to update the engine.

## Solution 2: Resintall VS2015 without Update 3

Follow the instruction from Infected_Post [here](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/435600/build-failed-with-vs-2015-update-3.html).

Below is what he has posted:

> 1. Completely uninstall visual studio
> 2. Use the Extra visual studio uninstall cleaner. Found on 
>      `github > Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases`
> 3. Delete the remaining Visual Studio installation folder.
> 4. Do a restart and this machine should be ready for a clean installation
> 5. Download the Visual Studio 2015 installer without any updates: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146
> 6. Now make sure you do a custom installation and deselect update 3!!!
> 7. Once the installation is finished you need to generate visual studio project files for your unreal projects.